# insert into select query with two databases

Tags: insert, multiple-databases

Any body knows (insert into table1 select * from table2) query with two databases. Mean table1 is in one database and table2 is in second database,I want to insert records from table2 to table1 which have same structure but they resides on different database. Can we do that in PHP or MYSQL?

Comment: Connect to one database from PHP, selects the data from the table, connect to the second database, insert those data. You probably can't do this in one go.....

Answer (score 0):

[image: Do According To This!] Hey Man You Made a New Database? And Want to Transfer All Data from First Database to other? If Yes, Use This:

1. Open **MySql** There Will be **Export** navigation button in horizontal menu just in the middle.
2. Click it.
3. Just Click **Go** Button.

Otherwise man from php its too difficult....

Comment: Hi. So much thanks for reply. But this does not help me as i want to do this via PHP. I have two databases on two different servers. I want to insert records into one database from other. I can do but my logic takes alot of time that is first i get records from on database and then start loop and then start each record in the loop. Now i want to use query "insert into table1(first remote database) select * from table2 (second database)". This will take less time but nor working for remote servers for me.

Comment: man i think so it is not possible because you cannot insert records to the database which is running on another server. If you have php file in Server 1 you can only add records to the Database of Server 1 with the help of that php file. You can't add them in Server 2's Database. I tried this before but it gives a error something " **Cannot Connect to Database. Using Password 'Yes'.** " . Man Sorry, But I can't help You. I am Just a beginner of web developing!